exporting a function thet takes a Win32 VARIANT parameter in a c++20 module
I'm very new to c++20 modules and i'm trying this:
VariantFunctions.ixx
export module VariantFunctions;

struct tagVARIANT;  // Forward declaration of VARIANT type
typedef struct tagVARIANT VARIANT;

export bool IsNonZeroI4x(const VARIANT & v) noexcept;

I'm trying to call this function from Win32 code which uses MFC like this:
VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
IsNonZeroI4x(v);

The compiler (Visual Studio 2022, 17.11.3) tells me:

error C2664: 'bool IsNonZeroI4x(const VARIANT &) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'VARIANT' to 'const VARIANT &'

I can write a similar function that takes a simple type, like a long in the place of a VARIANT, but I need to understand why the code above doesn't work.
I've tried to use #include <oleauto> in the .ixx file, but there's so many module-incompatible things in that header that it's not possible, hence why I pondered a forward declaration.

I'm not familiar with modules, but it sounds like the VARIANT in the module, and the VARIANT in the calling code, are being treated as separate independent types, not as the same type.
